# Inject additional parameters into a JavaScript callback function

Tags: javascript, syntax, google-visualization

I have spend a lot of time trying to find a title that explain my question, but not easy. Feel free to suggest.

Code is as follow: I am creating annotation for my chart using google visualisation. The annotation column uses a custom function. This is allowed by google, and the function will received 2 parameters: dt and row. The question is: what should (dt, row, i) in the below be so that I get the default dt, row that the function normally receives and my additional parameter i?

```
view = new google.visualization.DataView(chartData);
var arr = [0];

for (var i = 1; i < chartData.getNumberOfColumns() ; i++) 
{
    arr.push(i);
    arr.push({role: "annotation", type: "string", calc: (function (dt, row,i)  {
        if (typeof (dt.getValue(row,i)) == "number" && dt.getValue(row,i) == 0) 
        {
            return ""; 
        }
        else 
        { 
            return dt.getValue(row, i).toString; 
        }
    })(dt, row, i)
});
}

view.setColumns(arr);
chartData = view.toDataTable();
```

Comment: can you use jQuery ??

Comment: Sure. How would I use jQuerry to solve this?

Comment: A title that I feel describes better your question would be; Inject additional parameters into a JavaScript callback function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if i got it right, but you can probably use a higher order function for that:

```
var createCalc = function(i){
    return function(dt, row){
        if (typeof (dt.getValue(row,i)) == "number" && evs == 0) { return ""; }
        else { return dt.getValue(row, i).toString; }
    };
}

...
arr.push({role: "annotation", type: "string", calc: createCalc(i)});
```

Answer (score 1):

lets say you have a function `createCalc` which receives two parameters **dt** and **row** from the callback and you want to add your additional parameter **i** to it.
Create a function,

```
function createCalc(i, dt, row) {
  //functin code
}
```

and pass it as,

```
arr.push({role: "annotation", type: "string", calc: createCalc.bind(null, i)});
```

`bind` will return a new function adding parameters to it.
first argument, i have passed is `null`, it is actually will be assigned to `this` variable, pass appropriate value if u use `this` in your function.